# Ruby on Rails: CanCan and static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am using [CanCan 2.0](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0) gem for authorization and [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem for static pages.

In my routes.rb file I have:

```
match 'about' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'about'
```

And I want to make it public in my ability.rb file, but none of these two lines do that:

```
can :read, :pages
can :read, 'high_voltage/pages'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this problem related to the fact that there is no model 'Page'? There is [cancan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers), how to deal with this situation: it should work when you add

```
authorize_resource :class => false
```

to your controller.

Answer (score -2):

If it's static pages in the traditional sense, then that won't work. Static pages completely bypass the Rails stack and are served directly from the file system. What I would recommend doing is still caching these as static pages, but having a controller that checks the permission and then serves the static page.

Comment: Surely he just means a page that isn't a resource, ie but still in the stack?